# ios::right only works once C++

Tags: c++

I have no idea why `ios::right` works once. totally nothing

Same problem with `ios::hex`, `ios::decimal` and a few others unless I do some insane codes and get them magically work again

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::ios;

int main() {
    int len;
    std::cin >> len;
    // w = len + 1;
    cout.width(len);
    cout.setf(ios::right);
    for (int s = 0; s < len; s++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= s; c++) {
            cout << '#';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }   
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Expected Output:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

What i get:

```
     #
##
###
####
#####
######
```

Tried This:

```
cout << ios::right << '#';
```

Didn't work.

Comment: please remove the `ios` tag from this question... every tag has a description, which explains when it should be used, and this is totally off-topic for the `ios` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `cout.width(len-s);cout.setf(ios::right);` inside the first loop because ios::right works only for one time. So it should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::ios;
int main() 
{
  int len;
  cin >> len;
  for (int s = 0; s < len; s++)
  {
     cout.width(len);
     cout.setf(ios::right);
     for (int c = 0; c <= s; c++)
     {
       cout<<"#";
     }
     cout<<"\n";
  }
  std::cin.get();
  std::cin.get();
}
```

But your code is not correct as per you required output , correct code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::ios;
int main() 
{
  int len;
  cin >> len;
  for (int s = 0; s < len; s++)
  {
     cout.width(len-s);  // to align properly
     cout.setf(ios::right);
     for (int c = 0; c <= s; c++)
     {
       cout<<"#";
     }
     cout<<"\n";
  }
  std::cin.get();
  std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not that `right` is temporary, but that the `width` is temporary, so the next character being output does not use the width given - in fact that's a good thing, or your second line would be `#    #`, so you probably don't want that!

The solution is to move the `width` call into the outer of your two loops (and recalculated the width accordingly as you get wider and wider output).

I'm intentionally not writing how you should do this, as you need to practice thinking about how thing work, not practicing `CTRL-C/CTRL-V`.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter and simpler way of doing what you want

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = n; j > 0; --j)
            cout << (i >= j ? "#" : " ");
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
6
```

**Output**

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

See http://ideone.com/fbrfpe demo.